# BroadcastReceiver gets killed if registered after device restart

Tags: android, widget, broadcastreceiver

I have a widget that should start a broadcast receiver when it is created. 
This receiver handles widget update when there was a battery change.

**This is my code:**

- AppWidgetProvider code:

  ```
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
  broadcastReceiver = new BatteryInfo();
  IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
  mIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
  context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, mIntentFilter);
  }
  ```
- BroadcastReceiver code

  ```
  public class BatteryInfo extends BroadcastReceiver {
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // some actions...
      }
  }
  ```

This works correctly after widget is added. Widget's onUpdate is called, then receiver keeps getting called when there is change in battery state.

Problem begins after device is rebooted. After device is back on, after few seconds widget reinitializes itself, again Widget's onUpdate is called, then receiver is called twice and instantly dies. This appears in logcat right after that:

```
1950-3391/? I/ActivityManager: Process [my process name] (pid 7752) has died: cch+4CEM 
1950-2013/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to [my process name]/.BatteryInfo
1950-2013/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to [my process name]/.BatteryInfo
```

Why does it matter if widget was reinitialised after reboot?
How can I ensure my receiver stays alive as long as widget is on screen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgot to `Unregister` your `BroadCastReceiver`? please check and if you have not `Unregistered` your `broadcastReciever` than do it.

Comment: Actually I did forget it, but unfortunately it does not fix my problem.. or I don't know how to unregister it. I tried both in onDeleted and onDisabled, and both context.unregisterReceiver and context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver, it changes nothing

Answer (score 0):

This is expected.

After reboting your device, all listeners are deleted and you should register them again. In this case, you need to listen to BOOT_COMPLETE events to register your broadcast again.
Something like:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    ...
    <application>
        ...
        <!-- UPDATE YOUR BatteryInfo RECEIVER WITH the INFO BELOW -->
        <receiver
            ...
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                ...
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

BatteryInfo.java

```
public class BatteryInfo extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(action) {
            Log.v("BatteryInfo", "Boot completed. Registering to battery info events");
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
            context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(this, intentFilter);
        } else if() {
            Log.v("BatteryInfo", "Battery event");
            // Some Actions
        } else {
            Log.e("BatteryInfo", "Action not expected: " + action);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help. Now after reeboot it starts by reregistring itself, few BATTERY_CHANGED broadcasts are received and as before process is killed and receiver stops responding.

Also, do I really have to use BOOT_COMPLETE? Since my widget reinitialises itself after boot anyway and I can use it to register reciever there?

Comment: Yes, You can register from there.. You just need to find a way to register the broadcast again after the reboot